# Pattern matching a binary in erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to pattern match a binary against this

```
  <<_:(A * ?N + A + B)/binary,T:1/binary,_/binary>>
```

However it seems erlang throws an error saying that variable T is unbound. Just a quick explanation: I want to ignore a certain number of bytes and then read a byte and then ignore the remaining bytes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't use expressions with variables in bit size according to [this explanation](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-December/071145.html). Try to bind first`IgnoreBytes=A*?N+A+B` and then match it: `<<_:IgnoreBytes/binary,T:1/binary,_/binary>> = SomeBinary`.

Comment: Yep. If you want to put it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bit syntax we can't use runtime expressions as bit size.
We can use only constants, compile time expressions like `_:(4*8)/binary` and variables: `_:Var/binary`.

In your case, solution is to bind `A * ?N + A + B` to variable first.

```
IgnoredBytes = A * ?N + A + B,
<<_:IgnoredBytes/binary,T:1/binary,_/binary>> = SomeBinary,
T.
```

It's Better explained in [answer from [erlang-questions]](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-December/071145.html)